# Notepad++ how to extract only 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 character capital lettered Words only in a document?

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors

Here's my input and the desired output. What's the best way to achieve this?

Input:

```
Agilent Technologies Inc
A
NEW YORK STOCK EXCHANGE, INC.
Wide
Medium  
1.47
Exemplary

ABB Ltd ADR
ABB
NEW YORK STOCK EXCHANGE, INC.
Wide
Medium  
0.97
Standard

Ambev SA ADR
ABEV
NEW YORK STOCK EXCHANGE, INC.
Wide
Medium  
0.85
Exemplary

ABB Ltd
ABLZF
OTC LINK ATS - OTC MARKETS
–
Wide
Medium  
–
–

Auckland International Airport Ltd
ACKDF
OTC LINK ATS - OTC MARKETS
–
Wide
Medium  
–
–
```

Note that some of them have 8 line paragraphs and some 7 lines.

Output:

```
'A', 'ABB', 'ABEV', 'ABLZF', 'ACKDF'
```

Thanks!

Comment: this looks like homework. you have likely studied how to make a class like [A-Z], how to say "this class should repeat for 1-5 characters", how to say "the match must begin at the start of the line", and how to match the end of the string.  put those things together (in the N++ dialect) and you have your answer.  https://myelite.flextechnology.co/notepad-regular-expression-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^([A-Z]{1,5})$|^.*\R?`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    (               # start group 1
        [A-Z]{1,5}      # 1 up to 5 capital letters
    )               # end group
$               # end of line
  |               # OR
^               # beginning of line
    .*              # 0 or more any character but linebreak
    \R?             # any kind of linebreak (i.e. \r, \n, \r\n), optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              # content of group 1, the capital letters
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I am a beginner, it helped. If I wanted the output in quotes, if I replaced `$1` with `'$1'`, it doesn't seem to work. Why is that? How can I get the comma separated output like in the question? I know I can just rerun the regex match again to add quotes to front and back of the line and comma, but is there a better `Replace with` string I should use to get the direct output?

Comment: @user285645: You can't get the final formatting in a single pass. Find: `\R` Replace: `','` ; then Find:`^|$` Replace: `'`